# Add class "active" to Actionlinks generated by loop in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I've written a button group using Actionlinks to filter certain products.
Now I want to add the "active" class to the clicked button. Does somebody now how to do this?

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">


 @Html.ActionLink("All categories","Index",0,new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
      @foreach(var category in ViewBag.AllCategories)
      {
          @Html.ActionLink((string) category.Name, "Index",new { categoryId = category.CategoryId}, new { @class="btn btn-default"})   
      }
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you not do this with just JavaScript?